# Microsoft Teams notifications via springboot app

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-teams, slack-api, microsoft-graph-teams, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Currently, slack channel is used in our spring boot application to post any updates/ notifications for a file processed successfully or not . The version I could see in pom.xml for the artifact “SimpleSlackApi” is “1.2.0”.
The requirement is to post the same notifications to “ Microsoft teams channel“ instead of Slack channel.
I am in search of a similar teamsApi which can serve the purpose .  Need to implement this in my spring boot application and remove slack notification from the same .

I have created a teams channel and added the webhook URL in the application.yml file for my spring boot project .But unable to figure out the corresponding package/ library / maven plugin to be included in my pom.xml to add the dependency like that of slack api . Refer attached screenshot from my pom.xml - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd6EJ.jpg)

Comment: While we check this with engineering team, sharing this sample which uses outgoing webhook - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/java-spring-webhooks-sample for your reference.

Comment: This can be done by performing a simple HTTP POST request to the Incoming Webhook URL endpoint. Most languages support this and HTTP POST requests are language agnostic.-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet#create-incoming-webhooks-1. 

Card format sample for sending message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL. For legacy message cards, we don't have any SDKs.

Comment: For adaptive cards , if this fits the needs and you are okay with the limitations for Incoming Webhooks, listed in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook, you can use available SDK package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/rendering-cards/getting-started, Unfortunately, there is none specifically for Spring boot, you could pull code from Android SDK version: https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/master/source/android